# How do CCGs/LCGs have an ongoing metaplot?

Tags: doomtown-reloaded, legend-of-the-five-rings, metaplot

I am told that there are some collectible card games and living card games that have a metaplot. For instance, I am told that Alderac Entertainment Group (AEG) has *Legend of the Five Rings* and *Doomtown: Reloaded* have an ongoing story in the background that is furthered as new sets come out. Apparently it's a pretty involved metaplot too, as I've heard of a lot of fans of the *Legend of the Five Rings* RPG complaining about the changes introduced by the CCG.

For instance, I have heard that throughout the run of the *Legend of the Five Rings* CCG, different people have become emperor and new threats (e.g. politcal coups, demon invasions) have emerged and apparently had a specific canon resolution (e.g. the coup failed but the emperor was mortally wounded, so dude X is the new Emperor). These events are all somehow established by the cards int he game and became canon, becoming part of the timeline and affecting those who play the RPG and read any tie-in media, such as novels.

How does this work? I'm having a hard time imagining a story being told as part of a deck of cards with one sentence flavor text on each of them. At first, I thought maybe new boxed sets included fiction stories in the rulebooks, but as far as I can tell, that's not the case.

So how do CCGs and LCGs have an ongoing metaplot?

For what it's worth, my experience with card games in the past is stuff like *Yu-Gi-Oh!* and *Pokémon Trading Card Game*, which definitely did not have metaplot (at least, not metaplot that was furthered by the card game itself as opposed to a TV show or other media).

EDIT: To clarify, it is my understanding that the *Legend of the Five Rings* CCG and *Doomtown* are not having their metaplot advanced by their corresponding RPGs or anything else, but they are doing it through the cards themselves. My question is *not* about a card game where the game metaplot changes based on some other media (e.g. Season 2 of a TV show has a storyline where the hero gets a new power, so a new card is released reflecting this story development).

Comment: Does my answer give you an idea of how it works? If not, is there a way I can clarify it further?

Comment: You realize Magic the Gathering has an entire team dedicated to creating an expressive and consistent world for the cards to be "from"? There are [over 60 books](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Magic:_The_Gathering_novels) and [hundreds of articles](http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/magazine/archive.aspx?tag=uncharted%20realms&description=uncharted%20realms) describe in vivid detail the worlds of the game.

Comment: @corsiKa, I was not aware of that for Magic. I haven't really played it nor have I met anybody who mentioned them. Perhaps it's not as prominent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to e-mail someone who is more familiar with the *Legend of the Five Rings* collectible card game and got a pretty helpful answer:

Consider for instance the [*Race for the Throne*](http://l5r.wikia.com/wiki/Race_for_the_Throne) storyline of the L5R card game. This was a storyline where the emperor's throne was vacant with no heir and there was a sort of civil war to determine who should become emperor.

One thing that you seem to have not been aware of is that AEG [publishes fiction stories online](http://www.l5r.com/fictions/) for L5R and their other games ([Doomtown too](http://www.alderac.com/doomtown/category/story/)). *Race for the Throne* had [a whole collection of stories](http://www.kazenoshiro.com/fictions/samurai-edition/) that talked about which people each clan put forth as candidates, what issues arose, who died in the conflict, and so on. This was where the majority of metaplot took place.

If the stories had something happen to a particular person, they would be reflected in a new version of their character in the next edition (or in the rare even that someone died in the fiction, they would be completely omitted from the next edition). For instance, *Race for the Throne* had Kitsuki Iweko as [a Daimyo](http://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=4414) as a reflection of the development she gained during the *Rain of Blood* arc (Diamond Edition) where she was just [a Samurai](http://imperialassembly.com/oracle/#cardid=4413).

Aside from characters, the cards also tended to reflect the events of the stories as well. For *Race for the Throne*, these were cards such as [The Throne Stands Empty](http://www.l5rsearch.com/db/search.cgi?cmd=detail&card_id=6872), [Claimants to the Throne](http://www.l5rsearch.com/db/search.cgi?cmd=detail&card_id=7183), and [Claiming the Throne](http://www.l5rsearch.com/db/search.cgi?cmd=detail&card_id=7556). Often times, flavor text quotes attributed to certain people were in fact quotes from the fiction itself.

AEG will also base the storyline off of the results of high level tournaments, particularly the world championships. If memory serves, the 2007 World Championships were represented in-universe as the [Celestial Tournament](http://l5r.wikia.com/wiki/Celestial_Tournament) where the winning player got to have their faction crown their champion as emperor, concluding the *Race to the Throne* arc. The winner of the world championships was a player who played a Dragon clan deck, so the Dragon clan champion, Iweko, was crowned Empress Iweko I.

It seems the specifics about the 2007 World Championships have been taken down, but I found similar info on their website for [the 2014 World Championships](http://www.l5r.com/2014/09/12/2014-world-championship-story-prizes/). For instance, there was the storyline event "Something Wicked…"

> *Even in the most prosperous of times, there are dire omens that must be heeded. In Rokugan, there is one omen that is darker than all others, one sign that causes the faithful to rush to shrines and temples and pray to their Fortunes and ancestors of choice for guidance and protection. There is one portent that is so dire that there can be no room for interpretation, but instead its presence affords certainty that there are dark and terrible things upon the horizon.*
>
> *The Porcelain Mask of Fu Leng has returned.*
>
> The winner of this tournament may select any one personality affiliated with his faction. That personality will be responsible for discovering the mask’s return to Rokugan, and will be among the first to realize what disaster looms upon the horizon.

As a result of this, future stories by AEG will involve whichever person the winner of the tournament picked to be the one who found the mask.

So the ongoing metaplot happens in a couple of ways:

- Fiction stories published by AEG
- Cards that reflect those fiction stories
- Input from players who win championships or other special events

I think that it's rare for the RPG to affect the CCG metaplot (which I think is partly why RPG players hate the CCG metaplot changes, especially since sometimes there are pretty drastic shifts in status quo). I suspect that's because the CCG is more of a moneymaker and story prizes are a really good incentive for those who care about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yu-Gi-Oh does have a Meta Plot that is advanced by game play. It has several, actually, that follow the histories and relations of the many archetypes.

As for your question, which I will simply summarize as "How do collectible card games and limited card games have Meta-Plots?" I will answer as follows:

Designers of card games often create stories when creating their cards and original characters, not unlike how authors might create a back story for their characters that may or may not make it to print. It is a natural part of creation to grow attached to what you spend hours upon hours designing.

I will use Magic: the Gathering to explain this. Imagine, if you will, being a traveler who explores the world (lands) and gaining knowledge (cards in hand) and allies (creatures/planeswalkers). The more you explore, the more powerful you become (playing 1 land per turn and/or playing stronger creatures). When you play a game, you are telling a story of a rivalry between 2 people that must, ultimately, end in someone's demise. A game of Magic: the Gathering could account for years of conflict in the world of Magic's characters. Are you a sliver slayer? Are you at war with the Goblins? Did you forge an alliance with Jace or Chandra in your travels? Will you learn the spells needed (draw the right cards) to defeat your opponent?

All of this can be portrayed as a story.

Comment: I've clarified in the question what I mean by a metaplot. I understand that a game with your friend can have an underlying story, but that's not what I'm talking about. Apparently, L5R and Doomtown have canon stories behind them, which are more expansive than "designer X imagined this background when they made the card."

Comment: Well, again, I come back to Magic: the Gathering, which also has a canon story line, with each expansion diving deeper into the world and expanding the universe. In Magic, you are installing yourself into the story line. Each card in each set represents an actual part of a story. All you do is play it out. http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Timeline

The same with Yu-Gi-Oh! - http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Card_storylines#Duel_Terminal_Storyline

The way to make a game where gameplay can have an effect on a story line is to make the ending completely up in the air until new cards are released.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine, if you will, a game like **MLB Showdown**, where the characters on the cards are actual, real-life baseball players. Some cards you play indicate tactics and actions in baseball; other cards represent players on your team. Every year, a new "season" comes out. Sometimes ballplayers change teams; most times, their stats rise and fall based on their real world abilities. Now imagine that the organized play for this game mandated that you used only the cards from the most recent season. You might find that players you liked were no longer good in your deck, or that new players popped up that outclassed older ones, or that your favorite player was now on another team entirely.

This is how metaplot in CCGs worked, especially when it comes to games from AEG. Each character card shows or references an event; each character card shows a significant persona in the story and the way they appear now, as opposed to last time. An expansion would show events from different parts of the changing storyline; characters would change, fortunes would rise and fall. The story of **Legend of the Five Rings** was basically an Asian-themed "*Game of Thrones.*" (Now imagine if you had Ned Stark in your deck; and then suddenly — well, you know.)

In particular, which factions were on top were determined by an aggregate of tournament reports around the world — the games being played would be translated after a fashion into changes in the world's fiction. This synergy was a great draw to some people, but alienated others, as you've heard.